# Why is the modulus operator giving wrong answer?

Tags: c++, string, io, stringstream, modulo

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    stringstream ss;
    ss << 32;
    string str = ss.str();
    cout << str << endl
         << str[0] << endl
         << str[1] <<endl
         << str[0]%10;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

> 32
>  3
>  2
>  1

Instead, the last line should be 3 as 3%10=3.

Comment: str[0] is 51 and 51%10 is 1

Comment: What do you get when you print `cout << +str[0];` and `cout << (str[0] - '0')`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are comparing it to the ascii value, which is 51 (0 is 48), modding that gives you 1. You should subtract '0' or 48 in order to get the real number from the car.

Comment: I recommend always subtracting '0'.  Not only is the intent of '0' immediately obvious in a way that 48 isn't, this will also port over to most systems that aren't ASCII-based and haven't arranged the numbers in an unusual fashion.

Answer (score 3):

The representation of a character is different from the representation of a number. Even if the character at `str[0]` is 3, it is the character 3 whose ASCII code(i.e its numerical representation) is 51. Since characters can be implicitly converted to an integer when performing operation that require integers you code is performing `51%10` which is 1.